# Amazon S3 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

This is the first time I use Amazon S3. I've read questions and answers. They all seem similar to this problem but none of the answers fixed it for me.

I can successfully upload pictures but I can get them to display them (403 forbidden status).

This is the bucket's policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1475848347662",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1475848335256",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::235314345576:user/userx"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketdev/*"
    }
]}
```

This is the CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

This is the user's policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Using this component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone-s3-uploader.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to note:

- Where to assign **permissions** for access to Amazon S3
- Which permissions to assign

**Where to assign permissions for access to Amazon S3**

Objects in Amazon S3 are **private by default**. There are three ways to assign permission to access objects:

- **Object ACLs** (Access Control Lists): These are permissions on the objects themselves
- **Bucket Policies:** This is a set of rules applied to the bucket as a whole, but it can also specify permissions related to a subset of a bucket (eg a particular path within the bucket)
- **IAM Policies** that are applied to IAM Users, Groups or Roles: These permissions apply specifically to those entities

If your intention is to keep the content of the S3 bucket private but allow access to a specific user, then you should assign permissions to the **IAM User** (as you have done). It also means that **you do not require a Bucket Policy** since granting access via any one of the above methods is sufficient.

See documentation: [Guidelines for Using the Available Access Policy Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html)

Also a **CORS Policy** is only required if a HTML page served from one domain is referring to content from another domain. It is quite possible that you do not require the CORS Policy -- do some testing to confirm whether this is the case.

**Which permissions to assign**

This is always confusing... Some permissions are associated with the **Bucket**, while some permissions are associated with the **contents of the Bucket**.

The following permissions from your policy should be at the **Bucket** level (`arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket`):

- s3:CreateBucket
- s3:DeleteBucket
- s3:DeleteBucketPolicy
- s3:GetBucketPolicy
- s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration
- s3:ListBucket
- s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads
- s3:PutBucketPolicy
- s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration

Other API calls (eg `GetObject`) should be at the object-level (eg `arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*`).

See: [Specifying Permissions in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html)

Therefore, the policy associated with your IAM User should look more like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This grants `GetObject` permission to objects *within* the bucket, rather than on the bucket itself.

Comment: first thank you for your answer. I followed all of your instructions and still get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: @Hideya, how are you accessing the objects from Amazon S3? Are you doing it via the console, browser or CLI? Are you including access credentials or are you just making an anonymous call (eg a URL with no user identifiers)?

Comment: you were right. That configuration fixes the problem. I just realized that the error comes from the component. Thanks much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just if some body will face with the same problem - be sure that all files was uploaded to bucket, because if you use "Add files" button it does not upload nested folders. Better use "drag and drop".